# How to make an user-defined decision tree in Angular/JS/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, decision-tree

I'm tasked with making an UI that allows users to make a decision tree by drag-and-drop, I'm thinking of using [GoJS](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/IVRtree.html), but cannot figure out how to

- Allow users to create/delete links between nodes,
- Add and remove nodes,
- Add choices into nodes.

I'd appreciate if somebody can guide me with some simple examples.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal decision-tree editor implemented in GoJS:
[image: ![enter image description here]

The complete source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Minimal Decision Tree Editor</title>
  <!-- Copyright 1998-2023 by Northwoods Software Corporation. -->
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="border: solid 1px black; width:100%; height:500px"></div>
  Selecting a node shows various buttons, including a button to add a new child node and link.
  <textarea id="mySavedModel" style="width:100%;height:250px"></textarea>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/gojs"></script>
  <script id="code">
const $ = go.GraphObject.make;

const myDiagram =
  new go.Diagram("myDiagramDiv",
    {
      // move or delete whole subtrees
      "draggingTool.dragsTree": true,
      "commandHandler.deletesTree": true,
      //"textEditingTool.starting": go.TextEditingTool.SingleClick,
      layout:
        $(go.TreeLayout,
          { layerSpacing: 100, setsPortSpot: false, setsChildPortSpot: false }),
      "undoManager.isEnabled": true,
      "ModelChanged": e => {     // just for demonstration purposes,
        if (e.isTransactionFinished) {  // show the model data in the page's TextArea
          document.getElementById("mySavedModel").textContent = e.model.toJson();
        }
      }
    });

myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
  $(go.Node, "Auto",
    // don't delete a tree root node
    new go.Binding("deletable", "", node => !!node.findTreeParentNode()).ofObject(),
    $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
      { fill: "tomato", stroke: "lightgray" },
      new go.Binding("fill", "isSelected", s => s ? go.Brush.darken("tomato") : "tomato").ofObject()),
    $(go.Panel, "Table",
      { margin: 6 },
      $(go.TextBlock,
        {
          row: 0, name: "Title",
          stroke: "white", font: "bold 11pt sans-serif",
          margin: new go.Margin(0, 0, 4, 0), editable: true
        },
        new go.Binding("text", "title").makeTwoWay()),
      $(go.TextBlock,
        {
          row: 1, name: "Description",
          stroke: "white", editable: true
        },
        new go.Binding("text", "description").makeTwoWay()),
    )
  );

// when a node is selected, show various buttons
myDiagram.nodeTemplate.selectionAdornmentTemplate =
  $(go.Adornment, "Spot",
    $(go.Placeholder, { margin: 12 }),
    $("Button",
      $(go.Shape, { geometryString: "M12 0 L3 9 M2 10 L0 12", strokeWidth: 3 }),
      {
        alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0, -5, 15),
        click: (e, button) => e.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(button.part.adornedPart.findObject("Title"))
      }),
    $("Button",
      $(go.Shape, { geometryString: "M12 0 L3 9 M2 10 L0 12", strokeWidth: 3 }),
      {
        alignment: new go.Spot(0, 0, -5, 40),
        click: (e, button) => e.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(button.part.adornedPart.findObject("Description"))
      }),
    $("Button",
      // this button is only visible if there are any children
      new go.Binding("visible", "adornedPart", node => !node.isTreeLeaf).ofObject(),
      $(go.Shape, "MinusLine",
        { width: 12, height: 12, strokeWidth: 2 },
        new go.Binding("figure", "adornedPart", node => node.isTreeExpanded ? "MinusLine" : "PlusLine").ofObject()),
      {
        alignment: go.Spot.TopRight,
        click: (e, button) => {
          // expand or collapse the subtree of this node
          const node = button.part.adornedPart;
          if (!node.isTreeExpanded) {
            e.diagram.commandHandler.expandTree(node);
          } else {
            e.diagram.commandHandler.collapseTree(node);
          }
        }
      }),
    $("Button",
      $(go.TextBlock, "N",
        { font: "bold 12pt sans-serif" }),
      {
        alignment: go.Spot.BottomRight,
        click: (e, button) => {
          const node = button.part.adornedPart;
          // make sure the tree is expanded first
          if (!node.isTreeLeaf && !node.isTreeExpanded) {
            e.diagram.commandHandler.expandTree(node);
            return;
          }
          // then can add new node data and new link data objects to the model
          e.diagram.model.commit(m => {
            // add a child node data to the model
            const nodedata = { title: "Step", description: "description" };
            m.addNodeData(nodedata);
            // add a link data to the model
            const linkdata = { from: node.key, to: nodedata.key };
            m.addLinkData(linkdata);
            // start the animation of the new node at the parent node
            const newnode = e.diagram.findNodeForData(nodedata);
            if (newnode) newnode.location = node.location;
            setTimeout(() => {
              // start editing the link label
              const newlink = e.diagram.findLinkForData(linkdata);
              if (newlink) e.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(newlink.findObject("Text"));
            });
            node.updateAdornments();
          });
        }
      }),
  );

myDiagram.linkTemplate =
  $(go.Link,
    {
      selectable: false,
      click: (e, link) => e.diagram.commandHandler.editTextBlock(link.findObject("Text"))
    },
    $(go.Shape,
      { stroke: "gray", strokeWidth: 2 }),
    $(go.Panel, "Auto",
      $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle",
        { fill: "white", strokeWidth: 0 }),
      $(go.TextBlock, "choice",
        {
          name: "Text", maxSize: new go.Size(100, NaN),
          stroke: "gray", textAlign: "center", editable: true
        },
        new go.Binding("text").makeTwoWay())
    )
  );

myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
[
  { key: 1, title: "Decision 1", description: "Consider a, b, and c.\nDo you want to do X?" },
  { key: 2, title: "Decision 2", description: "Do you want to do Y?" },
  { key: 3, title: "Outcome 1", description: "The end" },
  { key: 4, title: "Outcome 1", description: "one solution" },
  { key: 5, title: "Outcome 2", description: "another solution" },
],
[
  { from: 1, to: 2, text: "Yes" },
  { from: 1, to: 3, text: "No" },
  { from: 2, to: 4, text: "Yes" },
  { from: 2, to: 5, text: "No" },
]);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```